# Multiple text lines on a button. Each line has different text styles

Tags: android, button

Hi i'm trying to create a button with multiple lines of text. See below example. Each line of text has a different text size and colour applied to it. The button also needs to be able to send the user to the next page. Is this possible in XML? I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution. Thanks.

BUTTON HEADING TEXT(large green font)
1st button text (small grey font)
2st button text (small white font)

See example:

[image]

Comment: use listview instead of buttons,that will be easy to create with listview.

Comment: hi do u have any example code i could look at?

Answer (score 10):

Picture is not accessible. but according to your problem, you can implement a LinearLayout as main componenet and set its property clickable and focusable, and set its background to android.R.drawable.btn_default. Set orientation of this layout to Vetical.

Add as many TextViews of any style in this linearlayout in xml or dynamically as you want. But set all the TextViews focusable and Clickable property to false.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm new to android development i dont suppose you have a code example of this. Im a bit confused with "android.R.drawable.btn_default" part of your answer. are you referring to the java file?

Comment: Its default background drawable for button.

Comment: or you can use `SpannableString` as explained in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5260025/51966) to similar SO question

Comment: Adding code examples would greatly help here

Answer (score 5):

Html.fromHtml(string) can interpret some of the hmtl tags and you can hence use html to style the text of your buttons.

Assuming that you have defined your buttons in a XML file you can then set the text of the buttons like this in the Java code.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    String styledText = "<big> <font color='#008000'>"
            + "My orders" + "</font> </big>" + "<br />" 
            + "<small>" + "You have no current orders" + "</small>";
    button.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));

    // Attach a listener to the button that will make something 
    // happen when the button is clicked
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Put your Intent code here
            Log.d("onclick", "Button click registered");

            }
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I've used your code and it works with no probs. To align it to the left do I simply use <align="left"> ? Does the intent statement then go underneath "button.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));

Comment: The gravity of buttons is set to center by default. To get the text to  the left you have to write android:gravity="left" in the XML file in the properties of your button. I have also added some lines to my code above that explains how to get the button react to clicks. Put your Intent statement inside the onClick method.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. One final question to you I promise... can you set the font size in specific units rather than using <big><small> tags? I would ideally like the "My Orders" text to be a lot bigger than the "You have no current orders" text. I've used <font size="20px"> but nothing happens. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to ask whether line spacing is possible. Thanks.

Comment: No sorry the font size tag does not seem to be supported. I don't know about line spacing have never tried to achieve that myself. You can try the header tags like <h1> and see if it looks OK. Otherwise you are gonna have to go with the other answer that jeet wrote that will give you total control over the appearance of your buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can stack `<big>` and `<small>` HTML tags to multiply their effect:

```
private final String btnInnerHTML = "<big><big><big><font color='#000000'><b>%s</b></font></big></big></big><br/><small>%s</small>";
btn0.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format(btnInnerHTML, "Line1", "Line2")));
```